# saving value from inputs which are displayed/ added via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Part of a site I'm working on, involves adding `<input>`s using jquery, so as the user can insert further details, depending on their requirements.  I am getting a bit stuck in how to save the values when these are inserted in the input boxes generated via jquery.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/57xrg040/

```
<form id="multiphase" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<div id="step1"> .. </div>
<div id="step2"> .. </div>
<div id="step3"> .. 
<div class="shape" id="plan4_shape">
    <span class="bakkant">
    <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm" name="p4_width"/>
      <span class="times"> &times;</span> 
      <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm" name="p4_length"/>
 </span>
<script id="template" type="text/template">
<span class="bakkant" id="bakkant">
<input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm" name="p4_width"/>
 <span class="times"> &times;</span> 
 <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm" name="p4_length"/>
 <button class="close" id="close">&times;</button>
</span>
</script>
<button type="button" name="add_row" class="addrow" id="addrow4" onClick="addrow()">Add row</button>                    <textarea name="more_info" id="profiles" placeholder="Beskriv fritt, vilka kanter du vill få profilerade."></textarea>
</div>
<button  type="button" class="nasta" onClick="processStep3()">Nasta</button>
</div>
 <div id="step4"> .. </div>
<div id="step5"> .. 
<button  type="button" class="nasta" onClick="processStep3()">Nasta</button></div>
</form>
```

Jquery  to used to add more rows

```
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('#addrow4').click(function() {
    var $clone = $($('#template').html());
    $clone.attr('id', "bakkant" + ++i);
    $('.bakkant').prepend($clone);
  });

  $('.shape').on('click', '.close', function() {
    $(this).closest('.bakkant').remove();
  });

});
```

jquery used to process the step in which the inputs are found

```
function processStep3() {
  var hasValue = false;
  /*plan 1 */  
    plan1width = $("input[name='plan1_width']").val();
    plan1length = $("input[name='plan1_length']").val();
 /* plan 2 */
    plan2_1 = $("input[name='plan2_1']").val();
    plan2_2 = $("input[name='plan2_2']").val();
    plan2_3 = $("input[name='plan2_3']").val();
    plan2_4 = $("input[name='plan2_4']").val();
/* plan 3 */
    plan3_1 = $("input[name='plan3_1']").val();
    plan3_2 = $("input[name='plan3_2']").val();
    plan3_3 = $("input[name='plan3_3']").val();
    plan3_4 = $("input[name='plan3_4']").val();
    plan3_5 = $("input[name='plan3_5']").val();
    plan3_6 = $("input[name='plan3_5']").val();
    $('.measures').each(function (index, elem){
    if ($(elem).val()!=""){
   hasValue=true;
  }
  })
    if (hasValue) {
        _("step4").style.display = "block"; 
        $("#phase3").removeClass("phase");
        $("#phase4").removeClass("main_list");
        $("#phase3").addClass("main_list");
        $("#phase4").addClass("phase");
        $("#alert3").hide();

    } else {
        $("#alert3").show();
    }


}
```

At the end I would like something similar to: 
1 - width 1, lenght1
2 - width2, length2
ect depening on the amount of "rows" added.   The values are to then be sent via an email, so I would like to either save them as php varialbes, or in a textbox, which is then sent. This is part of a multiphase form, involving 5 steps.

This code will be processed in an email form -

```
if ($_POST) {
    $name = $_POST['firstlastname'];
    $guest_email = $_POST['email'];

    $empty = false;

            function IsInjected($str) {
            $injections = array('(\n+)',
                '(\r+)',
                '(\t+)',
                '(%0A+)',
                '(%0D+)',
                '(%08+)',
                '(%09+)'
            );
            $inject = join('|', $injections);
            $inject = "/$inject/i";
            if (preg_match($inject, $str)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (IsInjected($guest_email)) {
          echo "";

          } else {
            $email_from = $name; //<== update the email address
            $email_subject = "You have a new message from $name";


            // message 
            $message = "<html><body style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>".
            "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' 
            "</table>".
            "</table>".
            "</body></html>";

            $to = ""; //<== enter personal email here

                    // headers
            $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: $guest_email \r\n";
            $headers .= "BCC: $guest_email \r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;  charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
            //Send the email!
            mail($to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);

             echo $message;
 if(mail($to, $email_subject, $message, $headers)){ echo "Sent"; }else{ echo "Not sent";} 
                        //done. redirect to thank-you page.
 //  header('Location: back to form');
          }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where do you want to save the values?

Comment: These values would be used as part of an email, (works using php)  One option is to save them in a textbox, and then using the texbox as a reference, and another is to send them directly to php.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#somebutton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {};
    $('#someparentdiv input').each(function () {
        var id = this.id; // or $(this).attr('id');
        var val = this.value; // or $(this).val();
        // note radio buttons and check boxes behave differently but you're not using them
        data[id] = val;
    });

    $.post('/the/page.php', JSON.stringify(data), function (r) {
        console.log('/the/page.php said ');
        console.log(r);
    });
});
```

Comment: Does $.post('/the/page.php' refer to the php file used to send the email?

Comment: Yes, `/the/page.php` is the path to the PHP page.

Comment: trying to test it however it's giving me syntax error in var data {}.

Comment: var data = {}, there is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to save all the data in the textbox, you can send data directly. I would suggest you to wrap all your inputs into a `<form>` tag, and use [`jQuery.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method in combination with [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

But before doing that, I want to pay your attention that by cloning template in the way you do, all `name` and `id` attributes remain the same. You should better change them, `name` attribute is crucial for form serializing in that particular case.

Final code should look like:

```
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('#addrow4').click(function() {
    var $clone = $($('#template').html());
    $clone.attr('id', "bakkant" + ++i);
    $clone.find('input[rel=\'length\']').attr('name', 'p' + i + '_length');
    $clone.find('input[rel=\'width\']').attr('name', 'p' + i + '_width');

    // change other attributes

    $('.bakkant').prepend($clone);
  });

  $('.shape').on('click', '.close', function() {
    $(this).closest('.bakkant').remove();
  });
  $('.shape').on('click', '#send', function() {
    var data = $("#myForm").serialize();
    $.post('/script_url.php', JSON.stringify(data), function (response) {
       //response here
    });
  });
});
```

Don't forget to wrap inputs into the form:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">  
<span class="bakkant">
   <input class="measures" rel="width" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm" name="p4_width"/>
   <span class="times"> &times;</span> 
   <input class="measures" rel="height" id="plan4_height" placeholder="mm" name="p4_length"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hxzmhdwd/5/

Comment: They are already wrapped in a form, didn't add the form tags since this is just a small part of a much larger form.

Comment: Idea remains the same

Comment: Another question - does 'script_url.php' refer to the php file used to send the email?

Comment: is there a way to know if $.post('/script_url.php', JSON.stringify(data), function (response) { has worked?

Comment: Open browser's developers tools(f12), open network tab, than fire the request and watch for it. You can track everything there: headers, sent data, response etc.

Comment: it looks like the code is working.  However I still need to know what variables would represent the new input boxes in the php file?

Comment: make a var_dump($_POST); and you'll see them.

Comment: I did, however they are not showing up. The values of the original input boxes are appearing, however the new ones are not.

Comment: Are you changing their "name" attributes?

Comment: The name attribute is staying the same as the original ie p1_length and p1_width, for all of them.

Comment: It looks like var i = 0 is inside of $('#addrow4').click , it should be outside.

Comment: it is already outside - I'm assuming you mean - $(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('#addrow4').click(function() {
    var $clone = $($('#template').html());
    $clone.attr('id', "bakkant" + ++i);
    $clone.find('input[rel=\'length\']').attr('name', 'p' + i + '_length');
    $clone.find('input[rel=\'width\']').attr('name', 'p' + i + '_width');
    $('.bakkant').prepend($clone);
  });

  $('.shape').on('click', '.close', function() {
    $(this).closest('.bakkant').remove();
  });
     });